# How to access a instanciated class from another function?

Tags: java, c++, class

I don't even know how I could possibly call this.
Lets say I'm trying to call a an instantiated class from a method other then one that instantiated this class. (Might be hard to understand)

In java I would just do this:

```
public class MyClass {

    ExampleClass classIwantToAccess; // This line here is the important part.

    public MyClass()
    {
        classIwantToAccess = new ExampleClass();
    }

    public ExampleClass getWanted()
    {
        return classIwantToAccess;
    }
}
```

So I tried that in c++, But it doesn't work like I expected...

```
#include "Test.h"

Test test;

void gen()
{
    test = Test::Test("hello");
}

int main()
{
    // How can I access my class from here?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include `Test.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to separate *declaration* of class from it's *initialization* you can use pointers.

Because now you have something like that: `Test test;` - it will invoke constructor of class `Test`. To avoid that you can use pointers and write it like that: `Test *test;` - now `test` will only be a pointer to some object.

Then you can create (allocate) this object in another function. So your whole code would look like that:

```cpp
#include "Test.h"

Test *test;

void gen()
{
  test = Test::Test("hello");  //Func Test has to be static and 
                               //it has to return pointer to Test.
                               //Or you can use new Test("hello") here.
}

int main()
{
  //Now you can dereference pointer here to use it:
  test->foo();  //Invoke some function
  return 0;
}
```

Instead of *raw pointer* you can use smart pointer for example shared_ptr which would take care of memory management, like in java:

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<Test> test;

void gen()
{
  test = std::make_shared<Test>("Hello");
}

int main()
{
  //You use it as normal pointer:
  test->foo();  
  return 0;
}
```